# JPA Criteria to_date

Tags: oracle, jpa, criteria

I have a table where the date field is a varchar. Since it is a legacy application I do not want to change the datatype. I want to write the following query in criteria. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
select * from ucms_vu vu where vu.case_e_dt is not null and to_date(vu.case_e_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD') = to_date('2018-02-02','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using purely JPA, I believe that is not possible. Because you are wanting to do a specific manipulation in a not manipulable data.

If you use Hibernate too, [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) annotation resolves your problem.

You can create a attribute in your ucms_vu entity:

```
@Formula("to_date(case_e_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD')")
private Date caseE;
```

And your criteria would use this attribute to perform the query.

For Example:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Ucms_vu.class, "ucms");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ucms.caseE", new Date("your date 02/02/2018"));
criteria.list();
```

Comment: I used CriteriaBuilder.function and that actually worked

Comment: so please post a answer with your solution.